# Oracle error ORA-24344: correcto con error de compilaci¾n .De mi parte no se porque me genera ese error

Tags: oracle

Estoy tratando de crear triggers para todas la tablas del schema
Utilizando sql dinamico  la idea es que cada Trigger tenga como nombre la palaba
"T_" concatenao con el nombre de la tabla

```
DECLARE --funcion anonima

--creamos un cursor para almacenar los nombres  de las tablas
cursor c_tablas is 
    select object_name TABLAS From user_objects Where object_type = 'TABLE';

v_sentencia varchar2(5000);

begin

--recorremos el cursor
for t_tabla in c_tablas  loop
    --creamos la sentencia para cada tabla
    v_sentencia := t_tabla.tablas||'
    after insert or delete or update on '|| t_tabla.tablas ||
    ' for each row '|| 
    'declare '||q'[
    BEGIN  
            if INSERTING THEN 
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Esta insertando');
            
            end if; 
            if DELETING THEN    
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Esta eliminando');
            end if; 
    END]';
    
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(''||v_sentencia);

--ejecutamos la sentencia para cada tabla    
execute IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t_'|| v_sentencia;
end loop;
    
end;
```

Agradeceria cualquier aporte

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Elimina las etiquetas no relacionadas de la pregunta, ya que solo agregan ruido: lee [ask]. Además, ¿ejecutaste [`show errors`](http://dba-oracle.com/t_plsql_show_errors.htm) desde consola para listar los errores?

Comment: Disculpas sr. Ejecutando el show errors me lanza el error ORA-24344: correcto con error de compilaci¾n

Comment: Desafortunado y falta de originalidad su nombre de usuario

Comment: Cuál es la versión del motor de base datos?
La cuenta con la que se conecta si tiene el permiso para crear Triggers?